# WP7 Bing Maps Zoom level based on Push Pin collection locations

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Just a quick question regarding the use of the following code snippet:

```
var locations = CurrentItems.Select(model => model.Location);
map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations));
```

as suggested in this answer:
[Zoom to show all locations in bing maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308582/zoom-to-show-all-locations-in-bing-maps)

I am retrieving a list of geocoordinate asynchrounsly and binding these to a Bing Map using an ObservableCollection; copying the resultant data over to the main UI thread using:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( ()=> {...} )
```

My problem is that, I can't reference the map control within the Dispatcher (or can I??), so how can I apply the new Pushpin locations to the map using:

```
map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations));
```

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Map` ultimately derives from `DependencyObject` it actually has its own `Dispatcher`. As such you can do;

```
map.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations)));
```

Also, it's worth noting you only need to call `BeginInvoke()` if the `CheckAccess()` returns false. (`CheckAccess` is tagged with an `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)` attribute so it won't show up in intellisense, you'll have to type it manually). The common pattern is;

```
if (map.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false) {
  map.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => map.setView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations)));
} else {
  map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; my problem though, is that I am using MVVM. The View Model is retrieving the list of locations and binding these to an Observable Collection, which is updating the map. The map itself is not accessible from the View Model, so can I use map.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke from the View Model?

Comment: @StevieB Is there a reason that your view-model couldn't also inherit from `DependencyObject`?

Answer (score 0):

I perhaps you will find this post useful. To bind the view of the map and the ViewModel, the method described use a DependecyPropety : http://sveiberg.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/5/.

Comment: The second line of your answer doesn't make sense.