# Zoom map after calling SetView(LocationRect) on Bing Map control

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7.5 application where I map a number of markers.

My code runs in OnNavigatedTo, and is similar to the below:

```
if (points != null && points.Any())
{
    var markers = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = "...";
        textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(textBlock);

        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        pin.Location = new GeoCoordinate(point.Latitude, point.Longitude);
        markers.Add(pin.Location);
        pin.Content = point.Sequence.ToString();
        mapItems.Items.Add(pin);
    }

    //map1.ZoomLevel = 15; // Tried this as well

    map1.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(markers));
    markers.Clear();

    points = null;
}
```

Unfortunately, despite setting an initial zoom level of 15 on the actual control, SetView is zooming out more than necessary to fit all the pins in the map. However, if the phone turns off, or I manually shut it off, and then turn it back on, after resuming the map is zoomed in a perfect amount.

Is there a step I'm missing to correctly refresh the zoom level of the map after calling SetView?

I've tried replacing my SetView with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10534374/11912) to [WP7 Bing Maps Zoom level based on Push Pin collection locations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10515367/11912), but it's not working as I'd expect either.

Control (Lat and Long are set to actual values, which is the center of the region markers would be added to):

```
<my:Map Height="311" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440" CredentialsProvider="..." ZoomLevel="15">
    <my:Map.Center>
        <my1:GeoCoordinate Altitude="NaN" Course="NaN" HorizontalAccuracy="NaN" Latitude="0" Longitude="0" Speed="NaN" VerticalAccuracy="NaN" />
    </my:Map.Center>
    <my:MapItemsControl Name="mapItems" />
</my:Map>
```

Thanks!

Comment: setview changes the zoom level so that all your markers fit in the map. Thats the whole point of setview. Thus the intial zoom level is lost.